# Top down approach of longest increasing subsequence?

Tags: c++, stl, dynamic-programming

> https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-subsequence/

This the link of the question which I tried to solve using recursion + memorization technique but not able to solve my testcases only pass only up to 4 is also I don't know that whether my approach is correct or not.
Below this line is the code I tried:

```
int lis( vector<int>& nums, int i, int n, int prev, vector<int>& ls){
    if(i==n||n==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(ls[i]!=-1){
        return 1 ;
    }

    lis(nums,i+1,n,prev,ls);

    if(nums[i]>prev){
        int  num=1+lis(nums,i+1,n,nums[i],ls);
        ls[num]=1;
        return num;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
class Solution {
public:
    int lengthOfLIS(vector<int>& nums) {
        int  n=nums.size();
        int c;
        vector<int> ls(n+1,-1);

        lis(nums,0,n,INT_MIN,ls);
        for(int i=n;i>=0;i--) {
            if(ls[i]!=-1) {
                c=i;
                break;
            }
            else {
                c=0;
            }
        }
        if(nums.size()==0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else    {
            if(c==0) {
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                return c;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I want to know how to apply  recursion + memorization technique in this type of question. Everyone is teaching bottom up approach, not top down approach so it is hard to understand top down. So explain me how to solve this question?

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: @tadman please help me